# Is $\mbox{lcm}(a,b,c)=\mbox{lcm}(\mbox{lcm}(a,b),c)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, least-common-multiple

$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$Is $\lcm(a,b,c)=\lcm(\lcm(a,b),c)$?

I managed to show thus far, that $a,b,c\mid\lcm(\lcm(a,b),c)$, yet I'm unable to prove, that $\lcm(\lcm(a,b),c)$ is the lowest such number...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the highest power of prime $p$ in $a,b,c$ be $A,B,C$ respectively.

The highest power of prime $p$ in lcm$(a,b,c)=$max$(A,B,C)$

The highest power of prime $p$ in lcm$(a,b)=$max$(A,B)$

The highest power of prime $p$ in lcm$($lcm$(a,b),c)=$max$($max$(A,B),C)$

Can you see max$($max$(A,B),C)=$max$(A,B,C)$ ?

This holds true for any prime that divides at least one of $a,b,c$

Comment: Can you quickly explain to me please, why the highest power of prime $p$ in $lcm(a,b,c)=max(A,B,C)$?

Comment: @ArekKrawczyk, what is the definition of LCM? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Finding_least_common_multiples_by_prime_factorization

Answer (score 4):

With this type of problem, it's often useful to be aware of a particular order on $\Bbb N_{>0}$ -- at least if one is familiar with posets (partially ordered sets).

Namely, the poset $(\Bbb N_{>0}, \mid)$, where $a \mid b$, as usual, denotes that $a$ divides $b$. (One may readily see/prove that this indeed forms a poset.)

This order has the following properties:

- $1$ is the least element;
- $\gcd(a,b)$ is the *greatest lower bound* or *infimum* of $a$ and $b$: If $m \mid a$ and $m \mid b$, then $m \mid \gcd(a,b)$;
- ${\rm lcm}(a,b)$ is the *least upper bound* or *supremum* of $a$ and $b$: If $a \mid n$ and $b \mid n$, then ${\rm lcm}(a,b) \mid n$.

which together make it a so-called *lower-bounded lattice*.

By the general theorem that in any lattice, for a collection of sets $(A_i)_i$ such that $\bigcup_i A_i$ is finite, we have $\sup_i \sup A_i = \sup \bigcup_i A_i$, we are done immediately:

Taking $A_1 = \{a,b\}$ and $A_2 = \{c\}$ (note that $\sup A_2 = c$), we find that: $${\rm lcm}({\rm lcm}(a,b),c) = \sup\{\sup\{a,b\},\sup\{c\}\} = \sup \{a,b,c\} = {\rm lcm}(a,b,c)$$

---

Of course, to be able to use this argument, one requires some knowledge about lattices and posets. If you don't understand it at this point, don't worry: when you progress in mathematics, you're bound to encounter these concepts, after which you hopefully can appreciate this argument.

Answer (score 2):

The "universal property" of the $\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}\lcm$ is

> if $\lcm(a,b) \mid x$, and $c \mid x$, then $\lcm(\lcm(a,b),c) \mid x$.

Make a good choice for $x$, for which you can prove the hypothesis and/or the conclusion is useful.

Answer (score 1):

What you still want to show is that $lcm(lcm(a,b),c)|lcm(a,b,c)$. So what you want to show is that the least, or actually any, common multiple of $a$, $b$, and $c$ is a multiple of the least common multiple of $lcm(a,b)$ and $c$. This follows from the fact that a common multiple of two numbers is a multiple of their least common multiple.

Answer (score 0):

> Lemma:
> Let $l:=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,\dots,z)$.
> Let $m$ be a common multiple of $a,b,\dots z$.
> Then, $m$ is a multiple of $l$.
>
> Proof:
> We can write $m=ql+r$, $0\leq r<l$.
> Then, $r=m-ql$.
>
> Both $m$ and $l$ are a multiple of $a$.
> So, $r$ is a multiple of $a$.
> Both $m$ and $l$ are a multiple of $b$.
> So, $r$ is a multiple of $b$.
> $\dots$
> Both $m$ and $l$ are a multiple of $z$.
> So, $r$ is a multiple of $z$.
>
> So, $r$ is a common multiple of $a,b\dots, z$.
> If $0<r<l$, then $r$ is a common multiple of $a,b\dots, z$ which is less than the least common multiple of $a,b\dots, z$.
> This is a contradiction.
> So, $r$ must be $0$.
> So, $m=ql+r=ql$.
> So, $m$ is a multiple of $l$.

> $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)$.
> Proof:
> Let $l:=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)$ and $l^{'}:=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)$.
> $l$ is a common multiple of $a$, $b$ and $c$.
> So, $l$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$.
> So, by the above lemma, $l$ is a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$.
> $l$ is a multiple of $c$.
> So, $l$ is a common multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ and $c$.
> So, by the above lemma, $l$ is a multiple of $l^{'}=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)$.
>
> $l^{'}=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)$ is a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$.
> $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ is a multiple of $a$.
> So, $l^{'}=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)$ is a multiple of $a$.
> $l^{'}=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)$ is a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$.
> $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ is a multiple of $b$.
> So, $l^{'}=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)$ is a multiple of $b$.
> $l^{'}=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)$ is a multiple of $c$.
> So, $l^{'}=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)$ is a common multiple of $a$,$b$ and $c$.
> So, by the above lemma, $l^{'}=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)$ is a multiple of $l=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)$.
>
> $l$ is a multiple of $l^{'}$ and $l^{'}$ is a multiple of $l$.
> So, $l=l^{'}$.